# How to implement RLS policy correctly with a many to many relationship?

Tags: postgresql

I have the following schema. Each `calendar` can have multiple `member` associated with it, and each member can have multiple `calendar`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS event_manager.calendar (
    id UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
    created_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS event_manager.calendar_member (
    id BIGINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    calendar_id UUID NOT NULL REFERENCES event_manager.calendar(id),
    ory_id UUID NOT NULL, -- using the UUID of an external system
    created_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
);
```

Now I want to protect `calendar`. Each member can only select `calendar` that they are associated with. I have the following policy:

```sql
CREATE POLICY tenant_isolation_policy ON event_manager.calendar USING (EXISTS (
                        SELECT 1 FROM event_manager.calendar_member
                        WHERE calendar.id = calendar_member.calendar_id 
                        AND calendar_member.ory_id = current_setting('app.current_tenant')::UUID
))
```

But with that, I will get an error for the following `insert...returning` query, because `calendar` is selectable based on rows in `calendar_member` table, but `calendar_member` table needs to reference `calendar` during its insertion.

```sql
WITH ins AS (
        INSERT INTO event_manager.calendar
        DEFAULT VALUES
        RETURNING
            id,
            created_at
        ),
        ins_member AS (
            INSERT INTO event_manager.calendar_member(calendar_id, ory_id, role_id)
            SELECT 
                ins.id AS "calendar_id",
                current_setting('app.current_tenant')::UUID AS "ory_id",
                1 AS "role_id"
            FROM ins
        )
    SELECT NOW() -- doing something simple here
```

How can I tweak my policy to make work? Or do I have to bypass RLS during my insertion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create the foreign key constraint `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED`, so that it is checked at the end of the transaction rather than at the end of the statement. Then insert both rows in a single transaction, and insert into `calendar_member` first.

Comment: that is something that I am unable to come up with, I will give it a try thanks!